# How to catch error when removing a listener from a ValueNotifier in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, listener, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I have the following ValueNotifier in Flutter/Dart:

```
ValueNotifier<String> event = ValueNotifier<String>("");
```

And the following function that I use to change the listener when navigating through different pages:

```
  addEventListener(Function()? oldListener, Function() newListener) {
    if (oldListener != null && event.hasListeners) {
      try {
        event.removeListener(oldListener);
      } catch (e) {
        print("Error trying to change notifier: $e");
    }
    }
    if (!event.hasListeners) {
      event.addListener(newListener);
    }
  }
```

However, no matter which function I pass as `oldListener` parameter, even if it's a random function that is not the current listener, I don't receive any error when trying to remove it:

```
//Example 1
//Start the app
event.addEventListener(null, functionOne); //The first parameter is null because event has no listeners yet  

//Navigate to second page
event.addEventListener(functionOne, functionTwo); //No error is thrown, as it should be


//Example 2
//Start the app
event.addEventListener(null, functionOne);

//Navigate to second page
event.addEventListener(functionThree, functionTwo); //No error is thrown, even though functionThree is not the current listener
```

Is there a way to catch this error?

Comment: read this: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ChangeNotifier/removeListener.html

Comment: @pskink In the article it just says "If the given listener is not registered, the call is ignored", but I'd like to do something when it's ignored, such as throwing an error

Comment: check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/4d9e56e694b656610ab87fcf2efbcd226e0ed8cf/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart#L286

Comment: @pskink Sorry but I don't understand why you linked me to Flutter GitHub, where can I find what I need in the link you posted?

Comment: this is the source file of `ChangeNotifier` - as you can see there is no way to check if any listener is stored in `_listeners` list

Comment: @pskink Ok, but without knowing if there's any listener stored, isn't there a way to see if the removal fails or not?

Comment: no, you cannot know this, what do you need it for anyway?

Comment: @pskink To check where there are flaws in the process of adding and removing listeners